# App often crashes when fetching results from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I get an NSManagedObjectContext as follows:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

Then:

```
    var fetchResults: [AccountEntity]?
    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AccountEntity")
        fetchResults = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [AccountEntity]
    } catch {}

    if let accounts = fetchResults {
        for a in accounts {
            if let name = a.name as String! {
                self.nameTextView.text = name // crash
            }
        }
    }
```

It sometimes gets the data and displays the name correctly on the screen. Other times it crashes and says EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION...

Sometimes I get this error:

```
pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I added `malloc_error_break` as a symbolic breakpoint and it did stop but I don't know how to interpret the assembly code it shows.

Comment: `if let name = a.name as String!` => `if let name = a.name as? String`

Comment: Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Anyway, even if I set nameTextView.text = "John" it crashes. This leads me to believe something is wrong with the outlet connection, but they are connected fine and the circle is filled.

Comment: Seem to have a found a source of the error. It's another member of AccountEntity that happens to be `nil` in another part of the code. But why it doesn't crash at that point I don't know. Also, I'm checking for nil and even doing nothing with that conditional statement it crashes.